# Asp.net Core Identity - administration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Is there any opensource project for managing users, roles etc for Asp.net Core Identity? Something similar to what was there for the old Asp.Net Membership.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I've been using .net Core Identity described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity) and it's been working very well for me.  Maybe this wasn't released yet when you posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Identity Manager](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/). But last time I looked on it (some time ago now), it had to be installed as a separate project, independent from your main application. Though this might have changed now.

In addition to the project [wiki](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/wiki), here is a [write-up](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity) about this project - you can start from there.

Comment: Yeah, I know Identity Manager. I does not support AspnetCore identity(aka 3.0), so I had to implement it : https://github.com/skorunka/IdentityManager . Anyways, it does not support all the features of AspnetCore Identity. It is good for basic management